# SAP Hybris Installation and Deployment Architecture for production environment

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Any suggestion, how can I set up SAP Hybris e-commerce solution for the Production environment. I am looking for **standalone server setup** for **Hybris App**, **Admin console**, **Datahub**, **Solr** etc.

Like:

- First server will have **Hybris datahub** appserver
- Second server will have **solr index** server+search
- Third server will have **Hybris backoffice** and **log collection** server.

How to achieve this? I did all on one server before.

Comment: Please mention more detail what exactly you are looking for. And the Hybris version you want to use, so we can point you to the right source.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am planing to install  the newest Hybris with extended portfolio. On one server, we only want to install Hybris app server and solr index server+ search (extended portfolio). Could you please give some details how to achieve this and avoid data hub/ backoffice to be installed on the said server?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dear HybrisFreelance: Would you please reply me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dear HybrisFreelance:  I still did not get any answer. Would you please help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here, I am assuming you are using **Hybris version 6.6**

### Hybris datahub server

Datahub is nothing but the web application(`datahub-webapp-x.x.x.x-RCx.war`), which can be deployed on Tomcat as the normal web application.

---

### Solr server

You need to install standalone Solr server on the different sandbox then you need to configure endpoint in your storefront & back-office Hybris platform (server) local.properties file.

---

### Hybris Application server (Storefront server)

You can install Hybris suite, with your set of extensions(localextensions.xml). Restrict backoffice access by configuring your upstream server(web or load balancer).

---

### Hybris Application server for backend (backoffice)

Installation is same as storefront node. As mentioned above (with help of Apache /load balancer) you can restrict any storefront or internet request on this server.

---

### Centralized logging

Hybris OOTB there is [**centralized_logging**](https://help.hybris.com/6.6.0/hcd/af36215ea1e34c22a1e3cbb2d550f733.html) recipes, which can be used if you have **Docker** base setup.

Anyway, you can set up your own **ELK Stack** (Elasticsearch-Logstash-Kibana), which is a good combination as Log Management Solution (Open Source). You can use Redis for the large enterprise solution to decouple the Log Server & Log Shipper.

**Tools:**

- Logstash: As a log shipper and a log indexer
- Redis: As a broker – used as a queuing system
- ElasticSearch: As a log indexer – store and index logs
- Kibana: As a front-end viewer – a nice UI with useful extra features

---

### Advanced Application Monitoring

SAP Hybris Commerce Advanced Application Monitoring is a tool for analyzing network traffic within the Hybris system.

Advanced Application Monitoring is vital for administrating and monitoring the health of live, deployed systems. You can analyze and monitor running applications.

Advanced Application Monitoring is based on Spring's support for JMX With the Hybris solution.

---

### Monitor Data Hub

Java Management Extensions ([JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javamanagement-140525.html)) is a Java technology that supplies tools for managing and monitoring various Java software. Data Hub provides JMX services to assist with operational management and external management.

---

### You can find [**detail answer here**](http://hybrisdeveloper.blogspot.com/2018/03/sap-hybris-installation-and-deployment.html)

Comment: Dear HybrisFreelance: You are great. Your answer is very helpful.We also need a dedicated server for Hybris Monitoring + Log Collection Server – extended portfolio. I looked the links you provided, seems there is no procedure for that. Could you please give a bit hint? I will mark this as answered soon. Regards.

Comment: Find [my updated post](http://hybrisdeveloper.blogspot.com/2018/03/sap-hybris-installation-and-deployment.html) and the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! HybrisFreelance

Comment: I am glad this helps you, You can mark this as answered.